# Need to order data with two fields Linq

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have requirment two show grid  upper row 
if any row modified or aded  means need order by modifydate and added date

```
from p in ctx.Item 
orderby p.modifiedwhen,p.createdwhen descending
select new ItemViewModel
{
ItemID = p.id,
VendorID = p.vendor,
 Vendor = p.Vendor1.name,
}
```

Comment: Show sample data. This description is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite clear from the explanation what's your exact requirement, but ordering by the greater of the two fields might work for you:

```
from p in ctx.Item 
orderby (p.modifiedwhen > p.createdwhen ? p.modifiedwhen : p.createdwhen) descending
select ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put separate `descending` keyword for each `orderby` field. See below.

```
from p in ctx.Item 
orderby p.modifiedwhen descending,p.createdwhen descending
select new ItemViewModel
{
ItemID = p.id,
VendorID = p.vendor,
 Vendor = p.Vendor1.name,
}
```

Comment: not worked i need when your created a row it show upper of the grid but if this is achived by createdwhen field

Comment: but when user use to update any field then updated record need to top of the grid second is latest add or second  if he update two records then both two are on the top

Comment: this one showing me only latest added on the top

Answer (score 1):

You could try this;

```
var results =
ctx.Item.OrderByDescending(p => p.modifiedwhen)
    .ThenByDescending(p => p.createdwhen)
    .Select(p => ItemViewModel{ ItemID = p.id,VendorID = p.vendor,Vendor = p.Vendor1.name});
```

If that doesn't work then try swapping p.modifiedwhen with p.createdwhen